# NSOutlineView not updating

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, binding, nsoutlineview

I'm trying to hook up a view-based NSOutlineView to my model using an NSTreeController and bindings.

My model consists of a main Node class (and subclasses of it). Every node can have 0 or more children. I'm storing the children in a C array (of Node objects) for performance reasons. I defined the `childrenKeyPath`, `countKeyPath` and `leafKeyPath` properties of my NSTreeController and implemented them in my Node class:

```
- (NSArray *)childNodes {
return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:children_ count:childCount_];
}

- (BOOL)nodeIsLeaf {
    return childCount_ < 1;
}

- (NSUInteger)childCount {
    return childCount_;
}
```

When I add a new child, I call `[self willChangeValueForKey:@"childNodes"]` before and `[self didChangeValueForKey:@"childNodes"]` after inserting it into the C array.

I set up the bindings as described in the documentation. 
(I bound the Content Object of the NSTreeController to my root Node. I bound the Content of the NSOutlineView to the NSTreeController's arrangedObjects. I also bound the NSTextField to the NSTableViewCell's objectValue.name property)

The initial configuration (the root object and it's children) is loaded fine upon running the app. I can also add new children to the root object.

However when I try to add a new child to any node (*except* the root) that has no children yet (no disclosure triangle) the NSOutlineView doesn't update (still no triangle). The new node is inserted into the model correctly and the will/didChangeValue messages are sent, but the NSTreeController doesn't bother examining the new children array. Logging the 3 keyPath functions above doesn't print anything in this case.

If I close the parent and expand it again, then the nodes are reloaded, the disclosure triangle is shown and I can expand the node to see the new node I just added. Why doesn't the NSTreeController examine the changes, even though I sent the KVO messages when changing the children array?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is a bug in the View-based NSOutlineView. The NSTableRowView that is in place in that location is missing the button subview which it needs. When you collapse and re-expand the parent to the problematic row, the outline view re-creates the row view and correctly adds the missing button. What is needed is a workaround to programmatically force the outline view to re-create that row view without having to make any other visual changes.

Answer (score 1):

OK this will do it:

```
/* item is the item which has just had new children added */
[_outlineView reloadItem:[_outlineView parentForItem:item] reloadChildren:YES];
```

It might be inefficient, and it might even be fixed in Mountain Lion, but this works for me. You can limit the times you need to do this to when the item when from 0 -> 1 child (and vice versa?).